# How can I use the nonfree modules in OpenCV for Java?

Tags: java, opencv, surf

I want to use SURF for feature detection [found here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) and use it in a Java applicaion, however the nonfree modules are not included in the library by default, as they are patented.

How do I access this module? I have searched and tried a few things but none have worked; many focusing on Android, which I don't fully understand.

Can I add it when using cmake to build the library? or is there a better mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when I was using cmake, nonfree library module was selected as default. So you should have this module built in your lib folder. Nonfree module includes some functionality that may be patented in some countries. So you should be careful if you are building a commercial application adn you will sell it in one of these countries.

To use it, you need to add it to your references and include the headers.

---

**EDIT**

I checked the docs here : http://docs.opencv.org/java/ there seems to be no module with name nonfree and there is no class related to sift or surf. I thought it should be same with c++ library but I was mistaken.

On the other hand, people claim that they built it for OpenCV4Android. That means it can be somehow compiled unofficially for java as well but no one seems to overcome this. Like here : http://answers.opencv.org/question/11185/how-can-i-generate-java-bindings-for-non-free/

Also there is a issue here about this : http://code.opencv.org/issues/2825

So at the moment no solution out yet. Implementing a JNI and loading compiled c++ nonfree lib may solve the problem by the way.

---

**One more edit** :)

In a tutorial, someone implemented JNI for nonfree module to be used with android. I don't have enough knowledge to try it for java at the moment. But a volunteer would be nice to try this with java :

http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/opencv_nonfree_android_jni_demo

Comment: Thanks, I thought that as well, but there is no option for me to import the nonfree library. Do I need to add a separate library to my Java project? Also it is also for a Uni project, so I won't be selling it.

Comment: Checking my library folder I do have it there [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/MyOrwJr.png). But i remember reading that due to the patent issues you mentioned they took it out, so I'm not sure how to access it.

Comment: I was mistaken, I thought it would be similar wih c++ but it was not. Check my edited answer. If I have time in future, I may give it a shot

Comment: Thanks, I found that link before and it I don't fully understand it, was hoping there was a more elegant solution. I'll give it a try. Does it just run the c++ code within Java?